# Angular frequency of spring mass system

Tags: harmonic-oscillator, spring, angular-velocity

Why is it true that ω=√(k/m)?

Can't find a description of this anywhere

Comment: It's there in every textbook of Physics. The definition of simple harmonic motion(SHM) states that a = −ω$^{2}$x. Read the 1st paragraph of Chapter 12 of Concept of Physics, H.C. Verma

Comment: Hi. Please note that you are expected to have thoroughly searched for an answer before asking your question. And it's important to detail where you're stuck and why, in order to attract good answers. You can consider checking the [advice on writing good questions](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: -1 No research effort. *Can't find a description of this anywhere* Really?! Try googling your title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the basic equation for harmonic motion (which applies to harmonic oscillators as well) - $\dfrac{d^2 x}{d t^2} = -{\omega}^2 x \tag{1}$
and that the force acting on the block in the spring mass system is given by

$F = m\dfrac{d^2 x}{d t^2} = -kx \tag{2}$

where $k$ is the spring constant which is characteristic to a spring, which measures the stiffness of a spring.

Compare the two equations, and you have the angular frequency as $\omega = \sqrt{\dfrac{k}{m}} \tag{3}$